# C++ and ExprTk parser "use of deleted function" error

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deleted-functions, exprtk

I'm trying to use the ExprTk mathematical expression parser library within a class whose objects are to be stored in a vector of objects, which is a member variable of another class; however, when I try to push_back a new object in the vector I'm getting a lot of "use of deleted function" errors. Here is a simple version of the code that is giving me problems:

```
#include <exprtk.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class B {
public:
  double x;
  exprtk::symbol_table<double> symbol_table;
  exprtk::parser<double> parser;
  exprtk::expression<double> expr_obj;

  B();
};

class A {
public:

  std::vector<B> Bvec;

  A();
};

A::A() {
  Bvec.push_back(B());
};

B::B() {
  symbol_table.add_variable("x", x);
  expr_obj.register_symbol_table(symbol_table);
  parser.compile("x^2",expr_obj);

  x = 2.0;
  std::cout << expr_obj.value() << std::endl;

}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {

  A a_obj;

  return 0;
}
```

I haven't included the header library since it's nearly 40,000 lines, but it can be found here: http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/.

Here is the error message

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = B; _Args = {B}; _Tp = B]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = B; _Args = {B}; _Tp = B; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<B>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/vector.tcc:100:30:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {B}; _Tp = B; _Alloc = std::allocator<B>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:954:21:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = B; _Alloc = std::allocator<B>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = B]’
src/main.cpp:25:21:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted function ‘B::B(B&&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:6:7: note: ‘B::B(B&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class B {
       ^
src/main.cpp:6:7: error: ‘exprtk::parser<T>::parser(const exprtk::parser<T>&) [with T = double]’ is private within this context
In file included from src/main.cpp:3:0:
ext_libs/exprtk/exprtk.hpp:35289:7: note: declared private here
       parser(const parser<T>&);
       ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:62,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62,
                 from ext_libs/exprtk/exprtk.hpp:37,
                 from src/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = B; _Args = {B}]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<B*>; _ForwardIterator = B*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<B*>; _ForwardIterator = B*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<B*>; _ForwardIterator = B*; _Tp = B]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:311:2:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = B*; _ForwardIterator = B*; _Allocator = std::allocator<B>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/vector.tcc:426:6:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {B}; _Tp = B; _Alloc = std::allocator<B>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<B*, std::vector<B> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = B*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/vector.tcc:105:21:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {B}; _Tp = B; _Alloc = std::allocator<B>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:954:21:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = B; _Alloc = std::allocator<B>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = B]’
src/main.cpp:25:21:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘B::B(B&&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'obj/src/main.o' failed
make: *** [obj/src/main.o] Error 1
```

I'm pretty sure the issue has something to do with the push_back function and how the object is being copied; however, that's a bit over my head and knowledge of c++ (which is rather basic).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Basic gist is somewhere you're probably copying something that does not permit copying. Probbaly a pass by value where a pass by reference is required or a [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) when compiling to an older compiler standard. Note: `std::vector` does a LOT of copying, moving and assigning. Everything you put in a `vector` needs to at least be movable, and `Bvec.push_back(B());` will make a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `Parser` cannot be copied, and based on the signature of how copying was prevented, the copy constructor was made `private`, it's unlikely that it can be moved either (`private` copy constructers were what you used before the disabling of a special member function with the `delete` keyword was added to the language in C++11, the same time move semantics were added). You cannot have a `Parser` instance as a member of an object you want to copy (unless you're going to get really weird).

Comment: This is all enforcement of you not wanting to have multiple instance of the same `Parser` floating around. You will have to use a reference, most likely a pointer because references are a <expletive deleted> to copy assign, to a single instance instead.

Comment: And Why am I writing this in comments again? When will I realize I can <expletive deleted>ing answer questions?

Comment: OK. I'm OK with comments for now. Need more information. Does `B` need to keep the parser around? Could you not make it a local variable in the `B` constructor and simply store the result? If so, so you need `B` at all? What about simply popping the result of parsing into the `vector`?

Comment: Wow, what a simple solution I never would have figured out on my own. Making the parser a local variable in the constructor works perfectly! I don't need it after the .compile function. By the way, this was a contrived example of a much longer code - I do need the analogs of A and B in the real code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the ExprTk documentation (readme.txt), specifically Section 10.3 we have the following note:

> ```
> Note:  The  exprtk::parser  is  a  non-copyable  and  non-thread  safe
> component, and should only be shared via either a reference, a  shared
> pointer  or  a  std::ref  mechanism,  and  considerations  relating to
> synchronisation  taken  into  account  where  appropriate.  The parser
> represents an object factory,  specifically a factory of  expressions,
> and generally should  not be instantiated  solely on a  per expression
> compilation basis.
> ```

[Section 10.3](https://github.com/ArashPartow/exprtk/blob/master/readme.txt#L975)

Answer (score 1):

`parser` cannot be copied, and based on the signature of how copying was prevented, the copy constructor was made `private`, it's unlikely that it can be moved either (`private` copy constructers were what you used before the disabling of a special member function with the `delete` keyword was added to the language in C++11, the same time move semantics were added). You cannot have a `exprtk::parser` instance as a member of an object you want to copy (unless you're going to get really weird in custom special member functions and NOT copy the `exprtk::parser`).

This is all enforcement of you not wanting to have multiple instance of the same `Parser` floating around. You will have to use a reference, most likely a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) because references are a <expletive deleted> to copy assign, to a single instance instead.

But this raises the question of whether you need to keep `parser` around as a member at all. What about something like this:

```cpp
class B {
public:
  double x; // Not sure we need even this.
  double result;
  B();
};

B::B():
{
  // parser is handled with local variables.
  exprtk::symbol_table<double> symbol_table;
  exprtk::parser<double> parser;
  exprtk::expression<double> expr_obj;

  symbol_table.add_variable("x", x);
  expr_obj.register_symbol_table(symbol_table);
  parser.compile("x^2",expr_obj);

  x = 2.0;
  result = expr_obj.value(); // store instead of printing
} // parser and friends are no longer needed and discarded.
```